# Integration of $\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integration of $\dfrac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,\mathrm dx$

My try:

Let $u=\sqrt{x^2-1}$

Then $x=\sqrt{u^2+1}$

$x \,\mathrm dx =u\,\mathrm  du$

$$\int \frac{2u(u^2+1)}{u\sqrt{u^2+1}} \, \mathrm du$$

$$=2\int \sqrt {u^2+1} \, \mathrm du$$

True ? and what about the last integration?

Comment: $$2x^2=2(x^2-1)+2$$

Comment: $x = cosh u$ is possible here - you get cosh^2 though, can be integrated by developing identities

Comment: @AndrewDeighton : Could you write $\cosh u$ instead of $cosh u$?  The former is coded as \cosh u, and automatically provides proper spacing in things like $a\cosh b$ and $a\cosh(b)$ (I mention both of those examples to show that the spacing is context-dependent: there is less space to the right of $\cosh$ in the latter.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for the tip

Comment: The last one is easy to integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
x & = \sec\theta \\[5pt]
dx & = \sec\theta\tan\theta\, d\theta \\[5pt]
\sqrt{x^2-1} & = \tan\theta \\[5pt]
\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx & = \frac{2\sec^2\theta}{\tan\theta} \sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta = 2\sec^3\theta\,d\theta
\end{align}

The [integral of secant cubed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed) is well known to be challenging to those first encountering it, but it does not require advanced methods.

Answer (score 2):

Hint let $u=\tan (y) $ and $dx=\sec^2 (y)dy$ and then continue to get the integral which can be calculated

Comment: the questioner did transform to the form $\sqrt{u^2+1}$  - so it may be possible - in fact it is headed for $\sec ^3 u$ as mentioned elsewhere

Comment: Yes and then you can write it as $sec sec^2$ and then IBP the only thing is the requirement of integral of sec

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
x & = \cosh u \\
dx & = \sinh u \, du \\[10pt]
\int \frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx
&=\int \dfrac{2\cosh^2 u}{\sqrt{\cosh^2u-1}}\, \sinh (u) \, du \\[10pt]
& =\int {2\cosh^2 u} \, du \\[10pt]
& =\int {(\cosh (2u) + 1) } \, du \\[10pt]
& = (1/2) \sinh 2u + u \\[10pt]
& = (1/2) 2\cosh u\sinh u + u \\[10pt]
& = (1/2) \cosh u \sqrt {\cosh^2 u - 1} + u \\[10pt]
& = x \sqrt {x^2 - 1} + \cosh^{-1}(x) + k
\end{align}

$\operatorname{arccosh}$ can be expressed in terms of $\ln$ - note I developed some identities for $\cosh^2$ and $\cosh2x$, they can easily be found on line also, probably

Answer (score 2):

my hint:
$$\int \frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ dx=\int \frac{2(x^2-1)+2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ dx=2\int\sqrt{x^2-1}\ dx+2\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ dx$$
both integrals can be evaluated by substituting $u=\sec \theta$

Comment: Thanks, And this well be $={x\over 2}\sqrt {1-x^2}+{1\over 2}sin^{-1}(x)+2{\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|}$, true ?